# Display ® registered trademark symbol in Android v4.0 WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

The source HTML string (including the symbol) is coming from the strings.xml resource file, and is destined to be displayed in a WebView. I've tested with this in the resources:

```
<string name="MY_STRING">®</string>
```

- Using the actual trademark symbol in the resources (®), the projects builds, but when displayed in the WebView it shows as "Â®" (i.e. an "A" circumflex, followed by the registered trademark symbol) - i.e. two characters are shown, the first incorrect & unwanted.
- I see the same result when using the entity reference, `&#174;`
- Using `&reg;` fails, and the project does not build.

This is the code that pushes the string resource into the WebView:

```
String html = getString(R.string.MY_STRING);
((WebView)findViewById(R.id.terms_web_view)).loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

I also tried this, but it did not help:
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");

I pushed the HTML string to Logcat, and it looks fine - it shows the symbol correctly. So if the string is ok, and the WebView is set to use UTF-8, why is the symbol not displaying correctly?

**UPDATE**
I tested on other devices. I can only reproduce this issue on a Galaxy Nexus on Android v4.04. On a Nexus One v2.3.x, Wildfire S on v2.3.x and a Samsung Tab 10.1 on v3.2, it works fine. I've changed the question title to clarify this is an ICS issue.

Comment: String resources are not designed to hold arbitrary HTML, including arbitrary entity references. Try `"&reg;"` as a literal `String` with `loadData()` and see if it works. If it does, consider storing this information someplace other than a string resource.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a resource related issue as webView.loadData("<html><body>®</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8") produces the same (problematic) result.

Comment: That is not what I suggested, nor would I necessarily expect it to work. Try `webView.loadData("<html><body>&reg;</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8")`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying Mark. Pushing through &reg; does work, and makes sense. Feel free to add an answer and I'll mark as the solution. Thx.

Comment: @OllieC : try this `<string name="test_string" formatted="false">test to \u00AE </string>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String resources are not designed to hold arbitrary HTML, including arbitrary entity references.

You *might* be able to get an arbitrary entity reference to work if you pre-escape it:

```
<string name="MY_STRING">&amp;reg;</string>
```

IIRC, that should decode to `&reg;` after your call to `getString()`.

At the end of the day, you need to get `&reg;` to `WebView`. If you cannot determine a way to do that with a string resource, you will need to store this value someplace else.

Answer (score 1):

You are using loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8"); This method expect a html string in your variable html. But it is not. Try

```
String html = "<html><body>My text is ®</body></html>";
```

for instance.

--updated to have a full html document

And if you store it in a resource file use :

```
<string name="MY_STRING" formatted="false"><html><body>My text is ®</body></html></string>
```

Comment: Not it I'm afraid. webView.loadData("<html><body>®</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8"); produces the same result-> Â®

Comment: Are you sure about this attempt ? The text "My test is..." did not appear in your comment.

Comment: The code I used in the test was webView.loadData("<html><body>®</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8");

Comment: I have tried with prefix & suffix text, but it makes no difference. For whatever reason it seems the ICS browser does not render ® in the way it used to.

Comment: Luckily there aren't many in the resources (which come from a CMS) and I'm forcibly doing a String.replace() to @reg;  Ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is not and Android developer answer but just something simple if you're trying to text somebody and neither  Ⓡ nor ™ aren't available as symbols (like on my LG phone Android 7.0). Just copy those symbols from this message thread and send them in a message to yourself or stuff them in a quick memo. Then you have them readily available for future use.

Comment: This answer does not appear to be about WebView, which the question is asking about.