# How to show registered Ⓡ or trademark ™ symbol in dialog?

Tags: android

I have to show registered Ⓡ and trademark ™ symbol , in the message of an `AlertDialog`. I set a sting value with the registered and trademark symbol in res/string. But the symbol is shown as a question mark when the dialog opens. How can I correctly show the these symbols in the dialog. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using Ascii codes?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm

Comment: @Shervin i tried unicode.

Comment: @A.S. : Can you please let me know the ascii code about Registered Mark..As you solution work for trademark only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for Ⓡ symbol use &#174; and trademark ™ symbol &#8482;
```

Keep the value in resources folder where strings are stored, it should work as I currently tested the same and its working. See the dialog, I am attaching the screenshot for same.![image]

Answer (score 45):

try this

for Ⓡ symbol use `&#174;` and trademark ™ symbol `&#8482;`

Answer (score 4):

This might help you, use:

`<string name="MY_STRING">&amp;reg;</string>`

See [Display ® registered trademark symbol in Android v4.0 WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106278/display-registered-trademark-symbol-in-android-v4-0-webview)